# Import a .class-File to a .jsp-File using IntelliJ

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I try to create a dynamic web project using IntelliJ. I'm just testing this IDE, normally I use Eclipse.
I have problems with the import of a class. To reduce complexity, I created a HelloWorld program.

The code is fine. The IDE does not show any error. I used this line:

`<%@ page import="test.*" %>`

to import my package named "test". This package contains the class "MyClass". My project strucure is this:

[[img] click for project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vQ7K.jpg)

Copying this strucure to my tomcat ROOT-directory produces a Jasper-Exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /web/index.jsp
    MyClass cannot be resolved
    15:   <body>
    16:   <p>
    17:       <%
    18:           String output = MyClass.PrintHelloWorld();
    19:           out.println(output);
    20:       %>
    21:   </p>
```

What is the problem? I did it the way how everybody on the net says ...

Fyi, this is my jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.*" %>
<%@ page import="test.*" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Simple JSP-Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>
      <%
          MyClass my = new MyClass();
          String output = my.PrintHelloWorld();
          out.println(output);
      %>
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks and best regards,
localhorst27

Comment: Can you post the jsp file ?

Comment: @zillani I edited my post, i pasted the jsp code.

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of index.jsp on your editor, because I think intellij should show you error, if not then the test directory is marked as exclusion.

Comment: [click here to view the screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/BsR5C)

Comment: is there something in the WEB-INF\classes?

Comment: WEB-INF is an empty directory. IntelliJ's output directory for classes is out/production/

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of manually copying the output to the tomcat [let the IntelliJ do it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html?search=tomcat)
2. If you want to do it yourself build [the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/working-with-artifacts.html) (menu Build > Build Artifact...). The result will be in the `out\artifacts\web_war_exploded` dir

Comment: using the tomcat from IntelliJ produces me a blank page in my firefox. therefore i am using a VM with a ubuntu server with a tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<%@ page import="test.MyClass" %>
```

Comment: The error stays, but another one comes in addition: [click here to see the error](http://imgur.com/a/XDirQ)

Comment: Are you copying your files to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps ?